# Meteor Upload to AWS S3

Tags: meteor

I have a Meteor app in which I insert a document (title, description, customer, ...) into a database. The app is using Autoform, Simple Schema and Collection2. I now want to add the possibility to upload a file to S3.

To keep things simple, I would present a filepicker as part of the 'Create Document' and once the file is uploaded, the URL field (from Autoform), should show the URL of the document on S3 (once uploaded) so that the URL is eventually stored in the document collection when the create button is clicked. I realise there might be better ways, but wanted to keep things simple for now.

I have tried to combine the tutorial [here](http://themeteorchef.com/recipes/uploading-files-to-amazon-s3). The upload to S3 works, but I fail to get the URL for the uploaded file stored documents collection. The below screenshot shows the layout. Any idea's? [image: screenshot]

My current code can be found [here](https://github.com/wymedia/meteor-base-wim/tree/master/client/views/authenticated/admin/documents).

Comment: Can you narrow down where the error is occurring? For example, is the `storeUrlInDatabase` method call succeeding or failing?

Comment: Also, to help with debugging, don't `return exception`. Instead, `throw new Meteor.Error('file-insert-failed', exception.toString())`.

Comment: As such there is no error message. Let me try to clarify a bit: the files are being uploaded to S3 correctly and the URL is added to a 'Files' collection.  I could insert in the 'Files' collection a reference to the Doc._id (to which the uploaded file belongs). Rather than doing that, I'd like to use only the 'Documents' collection with a 'URL' parameter. That way I could use Autoform to create the user interface and then insert everything in 1 go in the 'Documents' collection. So question is how to get the S3 URL into the 'Documents' URL parameter. Pretty trivial...but staring blind at it.

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be autoform add-on packages that specifically address S3 file upload (see the "Files" section [here](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#community-add-on-packages)), but since you seem to be using this as learning opportunity, I'll try to explain how I'd do it using core meteor.

But first, before I forget, your uploader template is a child of `#autoForm` but has a `form` element of it's own. I think that will cause the generated HTML to have nested `form` elements (which is no-no). To fix that, I'd move the `{{/autoForm}}` before the `{{> uploader}}` and add an event handler for your submit button that submits the form using `$('#documentForm').submit()`. Note: I haven't tested that.

Now, on to your actual question. You are essentially asking how to modify something in a template (the value of the url field) from an event in a nested template (the `uploader` template). I'd do that as follows:

1. When an instance of the parent template is created, attach a `ReactiveVar` to it that will hold the URL of the uploaded file.

   ```
   Template.adminDocumentNew.onCreated(function () {
     this.url = new ReactiveVar();
   });
   ```
2. Provide a helper to get the reactive var.

   ```
   Template.adminDocumentNew.helpers({
     url: function () {
       return Template.instance().url;
     }
   });
   ```
3. Use the helper to set the value in the form.

   ```
   {{> afQuickField name='url' value=url.get}}
   ```
4. Pass the reactive var to the uploader template as the data context:

   ```
   {{> uploader urlVar=url}}
   ```
5. Use the reactive var to set the URL when the upload finishes (somewhere in [upload-to-amazon-s3](https://github.com/wymedia/meteor-base-wim/blob/master/client/modules/upload-to-amazon-s3.js)):

   ```
   template.data.urlVar.set(url);
   ```

I've created [a meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/kdes97XRaJorz7H66/inter-template) that demonstrates the basic idea outside of the context of `autoform` and S3.